# CLion cout opens command prompt window instead of using CLion's terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, command-prompt, cout, clion

When I do `cout << "test"` in *CLion* and then build it instead of writing it to IDE's terminal like *IntelliJ*, *PHPStorm* or any other of the *Idea IDEs* it opens a new command prompt window, writes it to that and them immediately closes the command prompt window so I can't see what was written.

Is there anyway to make things like `cout` write to *CLion*'s debugger instead of opening a command prompt window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

CLion can't properly handle missing DLL files and although I had a lib inside my MinGW lib folder, windows wasn't finding it and thus the application was erroring.

I moved the DLL to my windows folder and now it works fine.

Comment: What dll was missing? How does that relate to opening a terminal window?

Comment: Please provide information on what dlls where moved